# .htaccess configuration for 2 domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domain:

1. domain.it
2. domain.com

A hosting profile is activated on `domain.it`. In this hosting spaces I have 2 wordpress installation in these folders:

1. it
2. en

I have set-up the redirect of `domain.com` to `domain.it/en`.

Now if I type `domain.com` the browser redirect to `domain.it/en`.

How can I redirect also `domain.com/____` to `domain.it/en/____` ?????

Is it possible to do it always reading in the url bar `domain.com/____`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.it/en%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```